# Title of highchart rendering bad

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

im having a problem. I redimension a highchart with the following code:

```
$('.highcharts-container').eq(0).parent().highcharts().setSize($("#tabs").width() -50 , $("#tabs").height()*0.8);
```

The problem is that the title is getting into the chart

[image]

If I zoom and zoom out the graph it renders okay again

[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: can you provide a sample code in jsfiddle reproducing the same

Comment: in general chart title goes inside the chart when floating: true, which is false by default

Comment: floating is always false,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a couple of hours i realize that if I comment the line

chart.layOutTitles(); inside the render function works perfect. I know maybe its not the best choice but this works for me. Thanks for the answers